# Input not updated when incrementing with button on VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components called OrderComponent and ModalOrder (with vue-modal-js)

I passed the data from OrderComponent to ModalOrder, and in ModalOrder, I use an input tag to contain quantity_ordered and button to increment its value like this

```html
<!-- ModalOrder.vue -->
<input v-model="order.quantity_ordered" />
<button @click.prevent="increment"></button>
```

in my script tag

```js
// ModalOrder.vue
<script>
export default {
  name: "ModalOrder",
  methods: {
    beforeOpen (event) {
      // if there's a data passed from the OrderComponent, I put it to "order" data
      this.order = event.params

      // if there's no data passed a.k.a a new record, I have to set the default value to 0
      if (this.order.quantity_ordered == undefined) { 
        this.order.quantity_ordered = 0
      }
    },
    ...
    increment() {
      this.order.quantity_ordered += 1
      // this method will not increment the input UI, if it's a new record
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      order : {
        code: '',
        table_name: '',
        customer_name: '',
        employee_name: '',
        menu_name: '',
        quantity_ordered: ''
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My problem is whenever I want to make a new order data, then when I click the button to increment, the input value UI isn't incrementing

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to initialize `quantity_ordered` as a number and not a string i.e. `quantity_ordered: 0`

Comment: I included the video preview here https://giphy.com/gifs/ehDntZosN39B9oJpAc

Comment: What is the value of `event.params` for new orders? `null`, `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're falling prey to one of Vue's [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)...

> Vue cannot detect **property addition** or deletion

So for your new records, you would need to either set the property when you assign the new value to `order`

```js
this.order = {
  quantity_ordered: 0,
  ...event.params // if "quantity_ordered" is set here, it will override the default.
}
```

or dynamically *set* it after

```js
if (this.order.quantity_ordered == undefined) { 
  this.$set(this.order, 'quantity_ordered', 0)
}
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, you should also default your data property to `0` if it's meant to be numeric

```js
data: () => ({
  code: '',
  table_name: '',
  customer_name: '',
  employee_name: '',
  menu_name: '',
  quantity_ordered: 0 // 
})
```